# How can I get og:image from resource with VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

How can I get `og:image` from resource with `VBA` `excel 2007`

For example, this URL:

```
https://www.bbc.com/reel/video/p08jgfdg/the-truth-about-christopher-columbus
```

Comment: please include your coding attempt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a more recent version of Excel, you could try this:

```
Sub GetImageFromHead()

    Dim MyUrl As String
    MyUrl = "https://www.bbc.com/reel/video/p08jgfdg/the-truth-about-christopher-columbus"

    'Required library reference: Microsoft XML v6.0
    Dim HttpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set HttpRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    HttpRequest.Open "GET", MyUrl, False
    HttpRequest.Send
    
    Dim HtmlDoc As Object
    Set HtmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    HtmlDoc.Write HttpRequest.responseText

    'This next line makes sure that the JavaScript on the page gets processed before continuing execution of the code.
    DoEvents 

    'Required library reference: Microsoft HTML Object
    Dim MetaCollection As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Set MetaCollection = HtmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("meta")
    
    Dim HtmlElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    For Each HtmlElement In MetaCollection
        If HtmlElement.getAttribute("property") = "og:image" Then
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (HtmlElement.getAttribute("content"))
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

But since your question is for Excel 2007, you would have to define the `HttpRequest` like this instead:

```
    'Required library reference: Microsoft XML v3.0 or v5.0
    Dim HttpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set HttpRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
```

And if you wanted a function that would just return the URL as a string instead, you could easily edit the Sub procedure to make it a function taking MyUrl as a parameter and returning the string instead of using it to insert the image in the Activesheet ([like this for example](https://itty.bitty.site/#/data:text/html;charset=utf-8;bxze64,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)).

Comment: @DecimalTurn  I've put the code in a module, did all the references and I'm still not able to execute the code. Can you explain the implementation in case I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @bpy – I just realised your question had the `Excel-2007` tag. I've added something that should make it work for that version of Excel.

Comment: It breaks on `HttpRequest.Send`... Anyway... is there any chance of this could be a function so that I can get `MyUrl` from any cell, like this: `=GetImageFromHead(A3)`?

Comment: @bpy – If you tell me the run-time error code, maybe I could help. However, it's a bit hard for me to test it since I don't have Excel 2007. Regarding the function form, you can certainly do that by using `MyUrl` as a parameter, but what do you want the function to return? The image URL as a string?

Comment: ...I understand the lack of excel 2007 and I appreciate all your efforts. But is there way of identifying the error here? As for the second question: Yes! I would like the function to return the image URL as string. Many thanks, once again!

Comment: @bpy – Let's take this discussion to the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220384/my-room).